# AngularJS Controller Declaration -- Error: $controller:ctrlreg

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller

I have a basic controller in angularJs named "BasicController".
Below is my code (BasicController.js):

```
(function () {
       var app = angular.module("app", []);
       app.controller("BasicController", function ($scope) {
       alert(2);
       $scope.menus = ["Profile", "About", "Contact"];
    });
}());
```

But when I run this project below error showing. What actually error says I can't understand. Please someone explain that is the problem actually.

[image]

Comment: Follow the error link to see description

Comment: Is this the place where you create your `angular.module` for first time ?

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$controller/ctrlreg?p0=BasicController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not a good that you are following, You need to create a separate file for module and a separate file for controller. And include both of these files in your index file.
use this guidelines for best practices.
https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/tree/master/a1

Comment: Thanks a lot bro for your reference :)

Comment: Anything for angular. Enjoy :)

Comment: I was in a wrong track, After following johnpapa my problem is solved... thanks again bro and now I am enjoying angularJS :)